# Как извлечь содержимое тега?

Tags: html, python, регулярные-выражения

Всем Hi! Никак не могу вьехать в регулярки. Вот есть такой html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>#1 Page#</title>
</head>
<body>
<body text="#336699" bgcolor="#000000">
<div align="center"> <h1>Insert data ib Data Base</h1> </div>

<kbd>
text
</kbd>

</body>
</html>
```

Мне нужно получить текст который находиться в теге `<kbd>` 
Как? Ни разу не сталкивался с регеспами((( Тяжело...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С использованием регулярных выражений этого можно достичь так:

```
re.findall(r'<kbd>(.*?)</kbd>', src, re.S)
```

Отработает корректно, даже в случае нескольких таких тегов. Так же не забудте что все символы перевода строк попадут в найденный результат.

Но никогда, слышите? Никогда! Не парсите HTML регулярными выражениями, особенно если не понимаете что делаете!

Из вашего прошлого поста предполагаю что вы пытаетесь парсить свой же HTML. Если это тот же случай - смотрите в сторону API xml или json.

Comment: html не мой. Ну смысле не я его писал. Его пишут другие программисты, которое очень не хотят использовать API xml или json - говорят не положено из соображений безопасности. Мне тоже нельзя использовать никаких сторонних библиотек, а только то, что есть в комплекте с питоном(((

Comment: @toorook, объясните начальству, что если вы парсите и получаете данные, то это абсолютно равноценно выкладыванию тех же данных в json.